# Additivity of matrix norms?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be real-valued square matrices, and let $A = B + C$. What matrix norm, if any, satisfies $||A|| = ||B|| + ||C||$?

The Frobenius norm clearly does not satisfy this additivity requirement. Are there alternatives that do? If not, is there a proof that such additive matrix norms cannot exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No norm can satisfy this. If there is such a norm we get $0=\|0\|=\|A+(-A)\|=\|A\|+\|-A||=2\|A\|$ so $\|A\|=0$ for all $A$.

Comment: wow, you two were quick, thank you! Kavi's answer makes sense to me: a norm by definition must assign zero to the null matrix. From this, it follows directly that any additive norm assigns zero to every matrix.

Comment: I'm just wondering why then in the definition of a matrix norm, the requirement of sub-additivity is written with a weak inequality, i.e. $||B+C|| \leq ||B|| + ||C||$ rather than with a strict inequality, i.e. $||B+C||<||B||+||C||$. I suppose the definition is written so as to retain also *trivial* norms such as the norm that assigns zero to every matrix? (Kavi's answer shows, I think, that additive norms are trivial norms, rather than showing that they do not exist, right?)

Comment: For any norm you get strict inequality for some choices of $A,B,C$ and equality for some other choices.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!