# Normalizing a sum of matrices to scalar values that sum to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $C = A + B$ for $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}$, $C\neq 0$. Clearly,

$$C = A + B \Leftrightarrow 1 = A/C + B/C\,.$$

Now let $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$ for $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Is there a linear operator that people use to normalize matrix sums (to values in $\mathbb{R}$) in a way that is analogous to the example above for scalar sums? I.e. is there a sensible linear operator $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \Leftrightarrow f(\mathbf{C}) = f(\mathbf{A}) + f(\mathbf{B})= 1\,?$$

My first thought was to use a matrix norm for $f$, but that won't work because of the triangular inequality, as others were quick to point out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240028/additivity-of-matrix-norms).

Comment: (I presume $f$ can depend on $C$, in analogy with your scalar example.) If $g(M)$ denotes the sum of the entries of $M$, then $f(M) := g(M)/g(C)$ works.

Comment: You star! Why didn't I think of that? Thank you very much, I love this forum :) I'll accept this answer if you add it!

Comment: Or $f(X) = \frac 1n\operatorname{Tr}(XC^{-1})$, if $C$ is invertible, where $\operatorname{Tr}$ denotes the trace.

Comment: $C\neq 0$ in the real case.

Comment: Thanks @amsmath, this is a very helpful alternative, and I'll give it a try now in my application. In fact, I've just noticed that the sum-of-elements approach, while of course 100% correct as an answer to my question, isn't actually quite right for my application because three of the four RHS matrices in my decomposition have elements which sum to zero...

Comment: Yes, $C \neq 0$ in the real case, I'll update my question now, thanks @ThomasAndrews!

Comment: If $c_{ij}\neq 0$ for some $i,j$ you can define $f(X)=x_{ij}/c_{ij}.$